# Vim FuzzyFinder - how to add tags support for other languages

Tags: vim, coffeescript, fuzzyfinder

Specifically I want to use `FufBufferTag` in coffeescript files. I've added the following to my `~/.ctags`

```
--langdef=coffee
--langmap=coffee:.coffee
--regex-coffee=/^[ \t]*([A-Za-z_]+): (\([^)]*\))? *->(.*)/\1 \2/f,function/
```

(very basic coffeescript method regex so far)

If I run ctags from the command line, it works, but `FufBufferTag` still doesn't

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue with CSS; added the regexes to my .ctags and they wouldn't show up with FufBufferTag. After searching through FuzzyFinder's buffertag.vim, I discovered it was restricting the tagged languages. I was able to add this line to my .vimrc to enable CSS with FufBufferTag:

`let g:fuf_buffertag__css='--language-force=css'`

I assume something similar will work for your coffeescript definitions:

`let g:fuf_buffertag__coffee='--language-force=coffee'`